# How to apply a gradient overlay in a Drawable?

Tags: android

Using ColorFilter I'm able to get a nice result

[image]

But that's not quite mock exact. I'd like to get something like this

[image]

How can I achieve such thing without pre-processing?

Comment: I see no difference. I have a feeling that my designer would much rather work with someone like you.

Comment: share the drawable, i may be able to help. slight variation is observable in the orange ring

Comment: The second one has a smooth gradient.

Comment: I guess a **LayerList** might solve the issue. The first layer contains the GradientDrawable, and the second layer contains the white shadowed circle which has a **hole** that lets you see the gradient. This also means **you can change the gradient colors programmatically**.